# How to iterate over a collection and have access to previous, current and next values on each iteration?

Tags: clojure

How can I iterate the elements of a collection in Clojure so I can access the previous, current and next values in every iteration.

With the following vector:

```
[1 2 3 4]
```

I would like to have access to the following values in each iteration:

```
[nil 1 2]
[1 2 3]
[2 3 4]
[3 4 nil]
```

Comment: recursive function that takes multiple arguments & pass them as arguments to recur? Feels like I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @DavidBern can you put a sample of code?

Comment: Its so educating reading the questions & answers in the clojure community. I feel so stupid in comparison. The solution I had in mind was this:

(loop [prev nil, [current & next] [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]] (if (nil? next) current (do (println next)(recur current next))))

When looking at the answer given by Erwin, Im amazed over how much I have left to learn :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do it is by [`concat`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/concat)ting `nil` before and after the collection and [`partition`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition)ing it by elements of 3 with a step size of 1.

```
(def c [1 2 3 4])
(def your-fn println) ;; to print some output later
(map your-fn
     (map vec (partition 3 1 (concat [nil] c [nil]))))
```

(You can remove the `map vec` part if it is also fine if the elements are a LazySeq instead of a vector.)

Which prints:

> [nil 1 2]
>   [1 2 3]
>   [2 3 4]
>   [3 4 nil]

Comment: Didn't know about the `partition` function really useful!

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend the partitioning technique, but another trick is to `map` over staggered instances of the same sequence:

```
(let [s [1 2 3 4]]
  (map vector (cons nil s) 
              s
              (concat (drop 1 s) [nil])))

-> ([nil 1 2] [1 2 3] [2 3 4] [3 4 nil])
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `loop/recur` implementation utilizing destructoring.

```
(let [s [1 2 3 4]]
  (loop [[prev & [cur nxt :as more]] (cons nil s)
         result []]
    (if (seq more)
      (recur more (conj result [prev cur nxt]))
      result)))
```

Comment: Find it very difficult to understand this solution

Comment: @eliocs Once you have internalized destructoring this is quite intuitive to grasp, nonetheless if you need a generic reusable solution I'd do recommend a more functional construct like the other two answers.